# Top N rows performance with many columns in Clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table with approximately 60 million rows with 500 columns.
The `visit_id` column has a high cardinality (almost unique).
The table does not have any indexes, order by or primary keys on the `visit_id` column.

The following 'simple' query will take 25 seconds:

```
SELECT *
FROM large_table
ORDER BY visit_id DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

While only selecting the visit_id will be done in 200 ms:

```
SELECT visit_id
FROM large_table
ORDER BY visit_id DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Transforming the original query using a WHERE IN will improve performance to 600 ms:

```
SELECT *
FROM large_table a1 WHERE a1.visit_id IN(
  SELECT a2.visit_id
  FROM large_table a2
  ORDER BY a2.visit_id DESC
  LIMIT 20
);
```

Why is this WHERE IN construction needed to achieve this performance gain?
Shouldn't Clickhouse be able to do the ordering / limitation on visit_id before loading/using all the other 499 columns ?

Comment: "Should" and "does" are two very different things.  You would need to look at the execution plans, but it looks like you have found a fine work-around.

Comment: It's not the same query, need to sort external query too.

  `ORDER BY a2.visit_id DESC
  LIMIT 20
) ORDER BY visit_id DESC`

Comment: It's known issue, such optimization is not implemented, yet. Clickhouse is not designed to do `select * `. Moreover a documentation warn you to do not use `select *` and select only required columns.